# mutt reply function returns empty header fields

Tags: mutt

I have been using mutt for quite some time but I have reconfigured it for use with offlineimap. The problem is now that when I reply to an email the header fields "To, From, CC Subject ..." are left empty and it is impossible to send the reply. I have to paste the fields in by hand which is kind of annoying (what do we have computers for?).

Any hints, for I have not got a clue how to debug this problem.

Thanks

my muttrc

## ======================================================

```
   # Boring details 
set realname = "Ivo Keel"
 
set from = "<myid>@gmail.com" 
set use_from = yes
    # fills headers on reply 
set fast_reply = yes 
set envelope_from ="yes"
    
    # Check for new mail in the folders 
set mail_check=60 # mutt checks for new mails on every keystroke
                      # but not more often then once in 5 seconds 
set beep_new = yes

    
    # Use a signature 
set signature="~/.signature"
    
    # mailcap 
set mailcap_path="~/.config/mutt/mailcap"
    
    # Use msmtp rather than sendmail. Check that
    # the path is correct for your system: 
set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp"
    
    # If not set in ~/.bashrc: 
set spoolfile = "~/.maildir/" 
set print_command="/usr/bin/muttprint %s" 
set print_split set print="yes" 
set sleep_time = 0 
set reply_to = yes
    #======================================================#
    # Folders
    
   set mbox_type=Maildir
    #set mbox="~/.maildir/" 
set folder="~/.maildir/" # Local mailboxes stored here 
mailboxes =c32t/inbox =hibury/inbox =inbox 
set record="+/hibury/sent/" # Where to store sent messages 
set postponed="+/hibury/drafts/" # Where to store draft messages
    #set move=no # Don't move mail from spool 
set mask="!^\\.[^.]"
    
    
    
    #======================================================#
    # What to show and order of headers 
ignore * 
unignore Date: From: User-Agent: \
             Cc: Reply-To: Subject: Mail-Followup-To: 
hdr_order Date From Subject To CC
    
set sort=threads 
set sort_browser=reverse-date 
set sort_aux=reverse-last-date-received
    #======================================================#
    # which editor do you want to use?
    # vim of course! 
set editor="vim" 
set edit_headers=yes # See the headers when editing
    
    #======================================================#
    # Aliases
    
set alias_file = ~/.config/mutt/alias # In their own file 
source ~/.config/mutt/alias # Source them 
set sort_alias=alias # Sort alphabetically
    
    
    # Odds and ends
    
set markers # mark wrapped lines of text in the pager with a + 
set smart_wrap # Don't wrap mid-word 
set pager_context=5 # Retain 5 lines of previous page when scrolling. 
set status_on_top # Status bar on top. 
push <show-version> # Shows mutt version at startup
    
set duplicate_threads = yes
    
    #email addresses with esc-1 and esc-2. Sets the status bar at the
    # top too so you know which from address you're using 
set mailcap_path = ~/.config/mutt/mailcap auto_view text/html
    
 

set query_command="abook --mutt-query '%s'"
    
    
    # Pager View Options --------------------------------- 
set pager_index_lines = 10 # number of index lines to show 
set pager_context = 3 # number of context lines to show 
set pager_stop # don't go to next message automatically 
set menu_scroll # scroll in menus 
set tilde # show tildes like in vim 
unset markers # no ugly plus signs
    
set quote_regexp = "^( {0,4}[>|:#%]| {0,4}[a-z0-9]+[>|]+)+" 
alternative_order text/plain text/enriched text/html 
bind pager R group-reply
    # View attachments properly. 
bind attach <return> view-mailcap
    
    #Skip some options 
set include=yes 
set forward_quote=yes 
set copy=yes 
set delete=yes 
set confirmappend=no
    
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Other configuration files
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #source ~/.config/mutt/account_hooks
    #source ~/.config/mutt/folder_hooks 
source ~/.config/mutt/colors 
source ~/.config/mutt/sidebar
    #source ~/.config/mutt/gpg 
source ~/.config/mutt/macros 
source ~/.config/mutt/lists 
source ~/.config/mutt/alias
```

---

END of muttrc

Answer (score 0):

Allowing mutt to automatically fill the From: header is done by adding:

```
set use_from = yes
```

to your .muttrc and allowing it to automatically fill the To: and Subject: header can be done by putting:

```
set fast_reply = yes
```

in your .muttrc. Those two options are very common, if you don't have them, you should consider looking at some of the .muttrc configurations available online to find other classical options (noconfirmappend, reverse_alias, sort=threads, etc.) which will greatly improve your mutt experience.

The CC: header will not be filled if you use the "reply" command instead of the "group-reply" one (the default keyboard shortcut is g).

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help. I included the muttrc file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but it turned out to be a problem with my workflow (the buggy system located between the keyboard and chair). Perhaps this was also your issue?

When I reply to a message in Mutt, Mutt drops me into a text editor session with pre-populated reply headers, like this:

```
1:  From: Steve HHH <steve@hhhdomain.com>
2:  To: Jonny Appleseed <jonny@hhhdomain.com>
3:  Cc:
4:  Bcc:
5:  Subject: Re: Good morning
6:  Reply-To:
7:  In-Reply-To: <CABSQ23i=yOa3GUwvbUPmHE+_i1_gLw@mail.gmail.com>
8: 
9:  On Mon, Sep 29, 2014 at 11:52:04AM -0700, Jonny Appleseed wrote:
10: > LOL
```

My mistake was to start typing the reply on line one. Mutt needs those headers on lines 1-7 (and the newline on line 8?) to stay *intact*. If I enter my reply on line nine, the reply fields are correctly populated when I exit the editor and arrive at the Compose menu.